# Property 'getTrimmedCanvas' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339), Signature Pad

Tags: reactjs, signaturepad

I am trying to implement a function into my app, so the User can sign PDFs. I found on CodeSandbox an example for a Signature Pad and i tried to insert it into my project but i get 2 errors called:

```
Property 'getTrimmedCanvas' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)

Property 'clear' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
```

[Codesource Signature Pad example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-signature-canvas-example-xevhz?file=/src/App.js)

**Codepart with the Errors**

```
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";
import SignaturePad from "react-signature-canvas";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import React from "react";

function Button() {
  const sigCanvas = useRef({});
  const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState(null);
  const clear = () => sigCanvas.current.clear();
  const save = () =>setImageURL(sigCanvas.current.getTrimmedCanvas().toDataURL("image/png"));

  return (

//for more Code use the Link: Codesource Signature Pad example

  );
}

export default Button;
```

I have installed this two libraries:

```
npm install --save reactjs-popup
npm install --save react-signature-canvas
```

Any idea how to fix them?
Thanks in adance

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this problem add a type  in the useRef:

```
const sigCanvas = useRef<any>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple you are using .tsx file which is causing the issue. Just change the file type from tsx to .js or .jsx it will work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just used `react-signature-canvas` and this works for me

On package.json

```
"@types/react-signature-canvas": "^1.0.2",
"react-signature-canvas": "^1.0.6",
```

On component

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import SignatureCanvas from 'react-signature-canvas';

const signaturePadRef: React.MutableRefObject<SignatureCanvas> = useRef(null);

return (
    <SignatureCanvas
      ref={(ref) => {
        signaturePadRef.current = ref;
      }}
    />
  );
```